# visual basic and access database, need an online solution

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I've written a database management program in Visual basic which uses a locally stored access database.  I need to see if it's possible to migrate it to a cloud solution but I'm a novice and I'm not sure if it's possible or how to code it.  Preferably, if possible, I would like to use Sharepoint because my team has a managed Sharepoint site we all have read/write access to.

Currently my connection string is:
`OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & "Data Source=mydb.accdb;")`

I've tried simply inputting a web address to my data source but it give me an "Invalid Storage Location" error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never tinkered with sharepoint, but take a look at the following link - it shows lots of connection strings (if that's your issue):  https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/